add config route to ng serve
I would like to add a specific route to the ng serve command, because I need to deliver a json file from that endpoint. It contains runtime config for the angular app. In the prod env this is easily done by configuring the web server accordingly, however in dev environment I am struggling. Right now I solved it by simply starting up an nginx that does the job an letting ng serve know about it via proxy.conf.json. This works as expected but feels a bit cumbersome. I would like to get rid of the dev nginx. Any ideas?

why don't you write a new script command like "start:dev": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json" in the package.json?

I have no issues with starting ng serve with my proxy.conf.json. I just need an additional route in the dev web server and don't know how to do it or even if it is possible.

can you please elaborate the problem with some basic examples, TBH i didn't understand the question properly.

I have some runtime config for the angular app which in prod is served under GET /runtimconfig.json by the prod web server. I cannot deliver that json file when I use ng serve, so the angular app is missing some required runtime config an will not run properly.
my proxy.conf.json:
{   "/runtimeconfig.json": {     "target": "http://localhost:4201",     "secure": false   } }
but localhost:4201 is an extra web server and not the one started by ng serve. I would like to get rid of the extra web server.

Or in other words I would like to define a GET endpoint in the proxy.conf.json (or some other/better place) that delivers a file instead of pointing to a specific host.

Make use of Environments - Angular Docs and hard code the configuration there, you will eliminate this complexity.
my-app/src/environments
├── environment.development.ts
├── environment.staging.ts
└── environment.ts

The file replacements will ensure, the correct configuration based on the environment.
"configurations": {
    "development": {
      "fileReplacements": [
          {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
          }
        ],
        …


We did that earlier. We came to the point, that there is some configuration which depends on the actual execution environment and so we needed to introduce to make runtime config available at runtime only, in other words, some config options we simply do not know at compile time.

@Martin Store those things as properties of a service and use them in a service. You can use environment.production boolean, to switch between properties

As I said, I do not know the values that go into environment.production.ts at compile time.

@Martin use the data in a service for runtime configurations, dont use anything else, the environment.production is a boolean value, that I set in the environment.production.ts to help angular understand that the current environment is production
